# Is there an easy way to supply data to Application Insights from normal win32 C++ code?

Tags: c++, azure, winapi

I'd like to know if there's something like a dll or lib (with headers, and possibly documentation) that can be linked into a normal* win32 C++ solution so it can (by function call) notify Application Insights of page views and send metric values.

This seems like it should exist and be simple to find, but I'm just going round in circles on Google, finding documentation for reading values back out via a web API, or using C#, or projects that other people tried in the past but now have no source available.

This is for updating a diagnostic tool which I'm trying to avoid having to completely re-architect because the logging now needs to go to a slightly different service.

*ie. not Winforms, C++/CX, Xamarin or UWP. Straight, command-line c++.

Comment: They seem to offer [public REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) (public preview as for 2017.05.24) which should be suitable for anyone.

Comment: The bits of REST API I found seemed to be for querying existing telemetry, not providing it in the first place so I avoided that track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no Application Insights client library for native applications (c/c++). Though it's in backlog I don't think it will be prioritized higher than java/node.js. So, I would not rely on its release anytime soon.

Customers who wanted to send telemetry from native applications usually picked one of the following options:

1. Using REST API directly. If application is going to use only couple of telemetry documents then it should be straightforward. With the most complexity coming from own requirements such as persistent channel.
2. Host CLR + use .NET Application Insights SDK
3. Have .NET service running on a box and implement communication channel between native app and this service.

Depending on environment (for instance, #2 makes sense if app already hosts .NET; #3 makes sense if there is already installed .NET service in addition to native app) you can check whether on of these options will work for you.

Comment: I went with a variant on #3, sending data over a socket to a .net service that then passed it on to AI usig the easy APIs it had access to.

Comment: were is REST API to POST data?

Comment: Hello from 22. I do not want Telemetry. Just login please. I assume by now it is clear Data Collector API should be used. That means REST. Has anyone ever tried this from Azure C++ code?  Should I look into [Azure SDK Core Library for C++](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/tree/azure-core_1.0.0-beta.1/sdk/core/azure-core)? It is still in beta it seems, Since Oct 2020.